# Unable to attach click handler onto iFrame in jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RP6WD/

Code:

```
 $('div').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');        
 });
```

The thing is, i have lots of iframes on the page which i need to attach click handlers to, so i can't really do anything with `.contents().get(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Im kinda newbie but something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RP6WD/3/)

```
document.getElementById("<iframe_id>").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
 alert("iframe clicked");
}
```